# Angular 2 life cycle hook methods using

Tags: angular

Every Angular 2 component has own life cycle. Each method can be used for special goals. But I can't find detailed information about what logic is better to use in each life cycle hook method and when each of them is used.

For example in constructor is the best place to inject needed dependencies.

Who can clarify this question in details (with examples and best practices)?

Answer (score 2):

It's very clear in angular.io itself, refer Bellow points

**TimingngOnChanges()**

Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.

Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

**ngOnInit()**

Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.

Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().

**ngDoCheck()**

Detect and act upon changes that Angular can't or won't detect on its own.

Called during every change detection run, immediately after ngOnChanges() and ngOnInit().

**ngAfterContentInit()**

Respond after Angular projects external content into the component's view.

Called once after the first ngDoCheck().

A component-only hook.

**ngAfterContentChecked()**

Respond after Angular checks the content projected into the component.

Called after the ngAfterContentInit() and every subsequent ngDoCheck().

A component-only hook.

**ngAfterViewInit()**

Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.

Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked().

A component-only hook.

**ngAfterViewChecked()**

Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views.

Called after the ngAfterViewInit and every subsequent ngAfterContentChecked().

A component-only hook.

**ngOnDestroy**

Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive/component. Unsubscribe Observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks.

Called just before Angular destroys the directive/component.

Comment: But there is no info what logic should be implemented in each method and in which cases it should be used